# Attach a user defined object to a Chart control?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015

I'm making extension methods to the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

The extension method add events to the MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove, MouseWheel. I also attach a ContextMenuStrip to the chart.

In the ContextMenuStrip I have some selections. Is it possible to save these states in an object that I attach to the Chart object somehow?

Or should I traverse through the ContextMenuStrip to get the state of the selections when needed?

For example the MouseWheel need to check if the "Zoom X" and "Zoom Y" are checked.

And the MouseDown must check if the "Scroll" is checked.

It would be nice to attach an object to Chart to handle these states.

For example:

```
public class ChartAddonState
{
    public bool scroll;
    public bool zoomX;
    public bool zoomY;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Tag as follow:

Instantiate first time in Form1_Load:

```
chart1.Tag = new ChartAddonState();
```

and you can use any where as follow:

```
(chart1.Tag as ChartAddonState).scroll = true;
```

or:

```
if ((chart1.Tag as ChartAddonState).scroll == true)
{ 
}
```